Unresolved import rustix::fs Error in Rust Smart Contracts on Windows
Encountering an error while trying to use the rustix::fs module in your Rust smart contracts when developing on Windows, while running cargo test.
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rustix::fs`                                                                                   
   --> C:\Users\aakip\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\near-vm-runner-0.26.0\src\cache.rs:294:21
    |
294 |         use rustix::fs::{Mode, OFlags};
    |                     ^^ could not find `fs` in `rustix`
    |
note: found an item that was configured out
   --> C:\Users\aakip\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\rustix-0.38.37\src/lib.rs:205:9
    |
205 | pub mod fs;
    |         ^^
note: the item is gated here
   --> C:\Users\aakip\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\rustix-0.38.37\src/lib.rs:202:1
    |
202 | #[cfg(not(windows))]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: found an item that was configured out
   --> C:\Users\aakip\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\rustix-0.38.37\src/lib.rs:318:16
    |
318 | pub(crate) mod fs;
    |                ^^
note: the item is gated here
   --> C:\Users\aakip\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\rustix-0.38.37\src/lib.rs:303:1
    |
303 | #[cfg(not(windows))]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Does that means cargo is not installed properly? I'm using windows. I guess fs module is available in non-windows platform. What alternate can I use to resolve the error?
